# How to constrain the every optimized vector component to be nonnegative?

Tags: python, constrained-optimization

I am building a gradient descent model based on portfolio optimization. Currently, I have finished the model and am able to run it smoothly without any problem. However, there's one issue that I couldn't fix: the optimal vector components have negative values. As my portfolio does not support short-selling stocks, this optimal solution may not be a convincing solution to my portfolio.

### Model Description

My cost function for the portfolio problem is defined as

$$F(x)=\frac{\beta_1}{2}(x^T\boldsymbol{\Sigma}x)-\mu^Tx+\frac{\gamma}{2}(e^Tx-1)^2+\lambda(e^Tx-1)+\frac{\beta_2}{2}\Vert{x}\Vert^2_2+\rho\sum_{i=1}^n\max(0,-x_i)^2$$

where $x$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ are my minimizer vector and positive definite covariance matrix. $\frac{\gamma}{2}(e^Tx-1)^2+\lambda(e^Tx-1)$ is the augmented lagrangian method for the constraint $e^Tx=1$ and $\rho\sum_{i=1}^n\max(0,-x_i)^2$ is the penalty imposing $x_i>0]$ for all components of $x$.

As can be seen here, my objective is to find the optimum solution for $x$ using the Steepest Descent method. Hence, I start to build my Python code as below:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

def penalty_f(v):
    return  np.sum([np.power(max(0., -xi),2) for xi in v])

def penalty_df(v):
    return -2.*np.array([max(0, -xi) for xi in v])

def aug_lag(lam, v):
    new_lam = lam + gam*(np.sum(v)-1.)
    return new_lam

def lipschitz(v):
    lips = beta_1*np.sqrt(np.trace(cov@cov)) + beta_2*np.sqrt(len(v)) + gam*len(v)
    return min(1,1/lips)

def project_f(v, lam_k):
    func = 0.5*beta_1*v.T@cov@v - b*mean.T@v + gam/2*(np.sum(v)-1.)**2 + lam_k*(np.sum(v)-1.) + beta_2/2*v@v + rho*penalty_f(v)
    return func

def project_df(v, lam_k):
    par_func = beta_1*cov@v - b*mean + gam*np.ones_like(v)*(np.sum(v)-1.) + lam_k*np.ones_like(v) + beta_2*v + rho*penalty_df(v)
    return par_func

def gradient_descent(f, df, ini_v, tolerance, lam, MAX_ITER=10000, output_fname='output.txt'):
    vec = ini_v
    negative = 0
    aug_lam = lam
    with open(output_fname, 'w') as out:
        for i in range(MAX_ITER):
            alpha = lipschitz(vec)
            f_value = f(vec, aug_lam)
            gradient = df(vec, aug_lam)
            direction = np.negative(gradient)
            vec += alpha * direction
            aug_lam = aug_lag(aug_lam, vec)
            print("No. of zeros: ", len(vec)-np.count_nonzero(vec))
            print(norm(gradient,2), "," , f_value)
            msg = f'{f_value},{norm(gradient,2)}, {str(list(vec))}\n'
            out.write(msg)

            # stopping criteria
            if norm(gradient,2) < tolerance:
                print ("The optimum vector for", {df}, " is at ", vec,"at iteration ", i+1)
                for i in vec:
                    if i < 0:
                        negative += 1
                print("No of negative: ", negative)
                print("Vector sum: ",np.sum(vec))
                print("Gradient: ", norm(gradient,2))
                break
            
            if i == MAX_ITER:
                print ('Higher no. of iterations is needed for', {df})
                print ("Vector: ", vec)
                print("Vector sum: ",np.sum(vec))
                print("Gradient: ", norm(gradient,2))
                
    return vec
```

Here is the result I obtained using 33 stocks:

```
The optimum vector for {<function project_df at 0x000001FA50FF2D30>}  is at  [-0.03442667 -0.01839447  0.03305939 -0.04319195  0.00353058  0.13003235
  0.09405175  0.00022958  0.08010633 -0.02831581 -0.04066535 -0.02875569
  0.04953858 -0.04019486  0.22866438 -0.03474848 -0.00029308  0.09792178
  0.11669689 -0.08569448  0.00405406  0.05544077  0.12273198  0.09615974
 -0.04374827  0.16994986  0.00670517  0.04772238  0.01729612  0.05218545
  0.03484764 -0.03438397 -0.00811171] at iteration  1230
No of negative:  13
Vector sum:  1.0000000001114249
Gradient:  9.961948573544883e-07
```

When I assess 30 or more stocks, negative components start to appear. Is there anything I can improve or take note of when performing portfolio optimization?

P.S. The data to the mean and covariance is in the link https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/rycj948t4bnq5u60m13ow/Covariance.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=d8u18ntuxk7wjcl1eup8gmxoa

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('Covariance.xlsx', sheet_name=0, header=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel('Covariance.xlsx', sheet_name=1, header=None)
np_cov_1 = df1.values
mean_1 = df2.values.reshape(len(df2))
ini_vec_1 = np.array([1. / (len(df2)) for i in range(len(df1))])
```

Comment: Maybe you can simply project after each iteration the negative components onto their limits. You should look into constrained optimization. Python has many suitable algorithms, so that you do not need to reinvent the wheel !

Comment: That's a good idea! But I'm quite a novice to all these optimization algorithms, so if you can show me some directions, that'll be progressive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's your value for the penalty parameter $\rho$? The penalty method is only guaranteed to give you a feasible solution (i.e., where the constraint is satisfied) if you let $\rho\to\infty$.

Comment: I have set all my parameters to 1 as a startup. The negative components remain when I tune up the parameter to a large value.

Comment: Are you doing this because you want to use gradient descent or because you want to solve this problem? If the latter, have you considered convex programming or mixed integer programming approaches?

Comment: Well, it's actually project-based research on the usage of gradient descent on portfolio optimization. That's why I wrote out the code for the SD method as a startup. Of course, I would definitely love to solve this problem in the meantime.

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew: You don't actually make your `beta_1` value and, presumably, others available. Can you please modify your question to contain a Minimum Working Example of the current state of your code?

Comment: Here is [an excellent paper](http://users.wfu.edu/plemmons/papers/nonneg.pdf) on nonnegativity constraints. I would recommend the Sequential Coordinate-wise algorithm described, starting at the bottom of page 10. It's quite simple but effective. (BTW, your Python code is very pretty)